# GroupBy with condition on aggregate Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate

I have a dataframe like this :

```
|   ID_VISITE_CALCULE|       TAG_TS_TO_TS|EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID|EXTERNAL_ORGANISATION_ID| RK|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------------+---+
|GA1.2.1023040287....|2019-04-23 11:24:19|            dupont|                    null|  1|
|GA1.2.1023040287....|2019-04-23 11:24:19|            durand|                    null|  2|
|GA1.2.105243141.1...|2019-04-23 11:21:01|              null|                    null|  1|
|GA1.2.1061963529....|2019-04-23 11:12:19|              null|                    null|  1|
|GA1.2.1065635192....|2019-04-23 11:07:14|            antoni|                    null|  1|
|GA1.2.1074357108....|2019-04-23 11:11:34|              lang|                    null|  1|
|GA1.2.1074357108....|2019-04-23 11:12:37|              lang|                    null|  2|
|GA1.2.1075803022....|2019-04-23 11:28:38|            cavail|                    null|  1|
|GA1.2.1080137035....|2019-04-23 11:20:00|              null|                    null|  1|
|GA1.2.1081805479....|2019-04-23 11:10:49|              null|                    null|  1|
|GA1.2.1081805479....|2019-04-23 11:10:49|            linare|                    null|  2|
|GA1.2.1111218536....|2019-04-23 11:28:43|              null|                    null|  1|
|GA1.2.1111218536....|2019-04-23 11:32:26|              null|                    null|  2|
|GA1.2.1111570355....|2019-04-23 11:07:00|              null|                    null|  1|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------------+---+
```

I'm trying to apply rules to aggregate by ID_VISITE_CALCULE and keep only one row for an ID.

For an ID (a group), I wish:

- get the first timestamp of the group and store it in a START column
- get the last timestamp of the group and store it in an END column
- test if EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID is the same for the whole group. 
  If this is the case and it is NULL then I write NULL, if it is and it is a name then I write the name. Finally if there are different values in the group then I register UNDEFINED
- apply exactly the same rules to the column EXTERNAL_ORGANIZATION_ID

```
RESULT :
+--------------------+------------------+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|   ID_VISITE_CALCULE|EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID|EXTERNAL_ORGANISATION_ID|              START|                END|
+--------------------+------------------+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|GA1.2.1023040287....|         undefined|                    null|2019-04-23 11:24:19|2019-04-23 11:24:19|
|GA1.2.105243141.1...|              null|                    null|2019-04-23 11:21:01|2019-04-23 11:21:01|
|GA1.2.1061963529....|              null|                    null|2019-04-23 11:12:19|2019-04-23 11:12:19|
|GA1.2.1065635192....|            antoni|                    null|2019-04-23 11:07:14|2019-04-23 11:07:14|
|GA1.2.1074357108....|              lang|                    null|2019-04-23 11:11:34|2019-04-23 11:12:37|
|GA1.2.1075803022....|            cavail|                    null|2019-04-23 11:28:38|2019-04-23 11:28:38|
|GA1.2.1080137035....|              null|                    null|2019-04-23 11:20:00|2019-04-23 11:20:00|
|GA1.2.1081805479....|         undefined|                    null|2019-04-23 11:10:49|2019-04-23 11:10:49|
|GA1.2.1111218536....|              null|                    null|2019-04-23 11:28:43|2019-04-23 11:32:26|
|GA1.2.1111570355....|              null|                    null|2019-04-23 11:07:00|2019-04-23 11:07:00|
+--------------------+------------------+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

In my example, I only have 2 lines for a group at most, but in the real dataset I can have several hundred lines in a group.

Thank you for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All can be done in single groupby call, however I'd suggest for the (slight) performance benefits and for readability of the code to split into 2 calls:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, size, collect_set, max, min, when, lit}

val res1DF = df.groupBy(col("ID_VISITE_CALCULE")).agg(
 min(col("START")).alias("START"),
 max(col("END")).alias("END"),
 collect_set(col("EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID")).alias("EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID"),
 collect_set(col("EXTERNAL_ORGANIZATION_ID")).alias("EXTERNAL_ORGANIZATION_ID")
)

val res2DF = res1DF.withColumn("EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID",
 when(
  size(col("EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID")) > 1, 
  lit("UNDEFINED")).otherwise(col("EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID").getItem(0)
 )
).withColumn("EXTERNAL_ORGANIZATION_ID",
 when(
  size(col("EXTERNAL_ORGANIZATION_ID")) > 1, 
  lit("UNDEFINED")).otherwise(col("EXTERNAL_ORGANIZATION_ID").getItem(0)
 )
)
```

The method `getItem` does most of the conditions in the background. If the set of values is empty, it will return `null` and if there is just 1 single value, it will return the value.

Comment: Hi Richard,
Thank you very much for your answer.
It works perfectly.
If I want to add columns that are in my starting dataframe but I do not have in the example that I gave previously.
For example, I have a column called "CANAL_LD" which always contains a unique value for a group.
I can not add it to aggregation with .withColumn.
Is there an "elegant" solution?
Thank you for your reply

Comment: Sure, if you don't have a specific logic as to how to choose a specific value in the aggregated group, you can always utilise `first` function, i.e. `df.groupBy("ID_VISITE_CALCULE").agg(first("CANAL_LD"), ...)` where `...` is the rest of the aggregates.

Comment: Hi Richard,
Sorry for the disturb.
I think that I had find the solution.
I use the function "first".
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all Richard.
Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0):

/It would be good if you show some code/ Sample Data from where dataframe is built.

Assuming you have a dataframe as `tableDf`

** Spark Sql Solution **

```
tableDf.createOrReplaceTempView("input_table")
val sqlStr ="""
    select ID_VISITE_CALCULE,
           (case when count(distinct person_id_calculation) > 1 then "undefined"
                when count(distinct person_id_calculation) = 1 and 
                     max(person_id_calculation) = "noNull" then ""
                else max(person_id_calculation)) as EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID,
         -- do the same for EXTERNAL_ORGANISATION_ID
        max(start_v) as start_v, max(last_v) as last_v
from
(select ID_VISITE_CALCULE,
           ( case
               when nvl(EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID,"noNull") = 
                    lag(EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID,1,"noNull")over(partition by 
                        ID_VISITE_CALCULE order by TAG_TS_TO_TS) then 
                        EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID
               else "undefined" end ) AS person_id_calculation,
            -- Same calculation for EXTERNAL_ORGANISATION_ID
            first(TAG_TS_TO_TS) over(partition by ID_VISITE_CALCULE order by 
                              TAG_TS_TO_TS) as START_V,
           last(TAG_TS_TO_TS) over(partition by ID_VISITE_CALCULE order by 
                              TAG_TS_TO_TS) as last_V 
           from input_table ) a
   group by 1
"""
val resultDf = spark.sql(sqlStr)
```